# Firefox bug: Links outside block elements

Tags: html, css, firefox

I've earlier heard that Firefox has a major problem with links wrapping around block elements, and it did recently give me some problems.

It is sometimes (maybe with a 20% rate), for some reason, changing this code (note that all the elements are defined as block elements in my stylesheet):

```
<li>
  <a href="product.htm">
    <img src="product-image.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Product image" />
    <h2>Product title</h2>
    <p>Product description</p>
  </a>
</li>
```

Into this:

```
<li>
  <a href="product.htm">
    <img width="100" height="100" alt="Product image" src="product-image.jpg">
  </a>
  <h2>
    <a _moz-rs-heading="" href="product.htm">Product title</a>
  </h2>
  <p></p>
  <p>
    <a href="product.htm">Product description</a>
  </p>
</li>
```

Which forces the stylesheet to display the elements in a totally wrong way; I use the *a* element to get a big link containing the product image, title and description in a webshop product list.

I want those big links and can't find an alternative way to do this. What would you suggest?

Comment: Include the relevant CSS. Also, you should make an example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Are you literally saying that the *browser* is changing your markup?

Comment: @Su' It could just be changing the DOM. Also, cool name.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc True enough, but that's also not quite the same statement as what's actually above, which is why I asked.

Comment: @Su' Sorry if I expressed me wrong - I do obviously mean the DOM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how authoritative a resource [xhtml.com](http://xhtml.com/en/xhtml/reference/a/) is, but they do say that the `a` tag can only contain:

> - Inline elements, except a, at any depth
> - Text

A possible solution would be to just reorganize your HTML so that it makes more sense (eg, not trying to put block-level elements in inline-level elements). Just have a single link for the product (maybe in the h2, or around the image). Then use JavaScript to detect a click anywhere on the `li`, and load the link.

Does that make any sense? [Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/sdleihssirhc/cUUaV/)

Comment: Note that `<a>` elements can contain block level elements in HTML5 in certain conditions, but Firefox 3 doesn't support that. Firefox 4 does, and won't cause the problem that the OP is seeing. Otherwise, good advice. +1.

Comment: That makes perfect sense; I guess that's the best way to maintain both UX, SEO and validated code.

Comment: @Alohci I hate sycophantically memorizing all these obscure XHTML rules, only to have HTML5 come along and throw them all out. :(

Comment: Actually XHTML doesn't have any obscure rules; from the point of view of the DOM, anything goes, as along as it's valid XML. It's HTML4 (and, to a certain extent, HTML5) that has all the obscure rules.

Comment: @Neil Even the obscure rules have obscure rules!

Answer (score 1):

Are *all* instances of these list items consistently coded? (Read: run the whole thing through the validator.) You said it only happens ~20% of the time, so you should first establish there's nothing different about the ones that break. This appears to be some kind of hyper-correction on the browser's part. A search for _moz-rs-heading turns up a bunch of old posts [like this one](http://oli-studio.com/bugs/mozilla/block-level-links.html). (Note the bug referenced there is fixed.) But in some of the cases, the people eventually discovered that their actual `<a>` tags were broken, they just weren't seeing it, and the modifications you're spotting were Firefox's attempt to handle it somewhat gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: the same HTML would display in a variety of ways. Literally each time I refreshed the page, Firefox broke my `<a>..</a>` into lots of smaller `<a>..</a><a>..</a>` blocks, each time in different ways. (Nearly) each time it displayed wrongly.

[This page](http://oli.jp/2009/html5-block-level-links/) is a good resource, it suggested putting a `<div>` directly underneath the `<a>`, but in fact the page my web designer had supplied, which didn't work, already had that.

So what I did, was to replace my `<div>` with a `<span style="display:block">` and that works now.

```
<a ...>
   <span style="display:block">
      ...
   </span>
</a>
```